# flowtype, how to monkey patch in a type safe manner?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using flowtype in my project, for convenience I want to extend the functionality of a library I'm using more specifically **luxon**

So, in Typescript whenever I want to extend the types of a library I can just do interface declarations and Typescript takes care of merging my types and those defined by the library, so it specifically takes care of this use case of mine

However I'm not able to find any information to achieve the same in `flow`, so far the only solution seems to be to take the flow-typed definition, copy it to my own type definitions (don't want to write on it, because every time I install a type via CLI, my changes would get lost right?) and modify it in place... which is to say a poor idea at best

[image: code sample]

Is there any mechanism I'm not aware to quickly extend library definitions in flowtype, without resorting to hard patching the existing type definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I made this work was moving the flow-typed definition into my custom definitions and manually adding the types there.

There is no way to merge/monkey patch flow types as of this writing.

Do yourself a favor go with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Flow is correct in that you shouldn't assign extra functions to a built in class. But if you really want to you can switch off flow errors per line with suppression errors.
https://flow.org/en/docs/errors/

Comment: Hmm, sorry I should have perhaps be more explicit, I wrote the question really fast, I know flow is right, the question is, how can I add my own definitions to the module types (from flow-typed), in Typescript you can do interface declaration and typescript automatically merges the type, is there any similar mechanism on Flow?

Comment: I think similar issue to https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/948 which still doesn't have a good resolution right now.